# Tail sigma field generated by i.i.d. sums

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

The random variables $(X_n)$ are i.i.d. real valued and in $L^1$. Let $S_n := \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $$\mathscr{G_n} := \sigma(S_n,S_{n+1},...).$$ Clearly the sigma fields $\mathscr{G_n}$ are decreasing. Then what will their limit $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty \mathscr{G_n}$ be? Will it contain only sets of measure $0$ or $1$?

Comment: Nice question. Clearly, assuming only independence, one can get nontrivial tail sigma-algebras.

Answer (score 0):

Every event in $\mathscr G_n$ is invariant by every permutation of the indices $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ hence the events in $\bigcap\limits_n\mathscr G_n$ are invariant by finite permutations. By [Hewitt-Savage zero-one law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hewitt%E2%80%93Savage_zero%E2%80%93one_law), every event in $\bigcap\limits_n\mathscr G_n$ has probability $0$ or $1$. The integrability of the random variables is not required.